# How to display YouTubePlayerView in a ListView in Android?

Tags: android, json, listview

The following shows error:

> NullPointerException: Cannot start activity component(a.b.YoutubeActivity)

Please check it out. Passing single videoID as of now stuck with NullPointerException. Following is my `VideoAdapter`:

```
public class VideoAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    public static final String API_KEY = "Xxxx-pcD82qk8";
    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "7UpbJKeiv_Y";
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    JSONArray jArray = null;
    ArrayList<YouTubeItem> list;
    private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;

    public VideoAdapter(Activity context,
                        JSONArray jArray) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        parseResponse(jArray);
    }

    private void parseResponse(JSONArray jArray) {
        if (jArray != null && jArray.length() > 0) {
            String date;
            String title;
            String link;
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            list = new ArrayList<YouTubeItem>();

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    date = jsonObject.getString("date");
                    title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                    link = jsonObject.getString("link");

                    if (date != null && title != null && link != null) {
                        list.add(new YouTubeItem(date, title, link));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
        String[] date = new String[jArray.length()];
        String[] title = new String[jArray.length()];
        String[] link = new String[jArray.length()];

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("adapter 1", "");

        View rowView = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.youtube_view, parent, false);

        }
        Log.i("adapter 3", "");
        youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
        Log.i("adapter 4", "");
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
        Log.i("adapter 5", "");
        TextView d = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Log.i("adapter 6", "");
        TextView t = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Log.i("adapter 7", "");
        TextView l = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        Log.i("adapter 8", "");
        d.setText(list.get(position).getDate());
        Log.i("adapter 9", "");
        t.setText(list.get(position).getTitle());
        Log.i("adapter 10", "");
        l.setText(list.get(position).getLink());
        Log.i("adapter 11", "");

        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return i;
    }

    private class YouTubeItem {
        private String date;
        private String title;
        private String link;

        private YouTubeItem(String date, String title, String link) {
            this.date = date;
            this.title = title;
            this.link = link;
        }

        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getLink() {
            return link;
        }

        public void setLink(String link) {
            this.link = link;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
                                        YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, 
                                        YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        youTubePlayer = player;

        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace you `Adapter` with this one

```
public class VideoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
JSONArray jArray = null;
ArrayList<YouTubeItem> list;

public VideoAdapter(YoutubeActivity youtubeActivity,
                    int activityYouTubeApi, JSONArray jArray) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    parseResponse(jArray);
}

private void parseResponse(JSONArray jArray) {
    if (jArray != null && jArray.length() > 0) {
        String date;
        String title;
        String link;
        JSONObject jsonObject;
        list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                date = jsonObject.getString("date");
                title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                link = jsonObject.getString("link");

                if (date != null && title != null && link != null) {
                    list.add(new YouTubeItem(date, title, link));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
    String[] date = new String[jArray.length()];
    String[] title = new String[jArray.length()];
    String[] link = new String[jArray.length()];


}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.youtube_view, parent, false);
    YouTubePlayerView you = (YouTubePlayerView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
    TextView d = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView t = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView l = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    d.setText(list.get(position).getDate());
    t.setText(list.get(position).getTitle());
    l.setText(list.get(position).getLink());

    return rowView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return i;
}

private class YouTubeItem {
    private String date;
    private String title;
    private String link;

    private YouTubeItem(String date, String title, String link) {
        this.date = date;
        this.title = title;
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }
}
}
```

Instead of creating three different Arrays, I created an Object called `YouTubeItem`. This will be more readable and easier to manipulate, avoid any problems if you have lost one attribute of any of the three arrays and make the parsing individual process (Invalid object will not affect the whole process)

Let me know if you have any more questions

Comment: With this example I get Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView