# can I put youtubeplayerview or youtubeplayerfragment in a custom listview?

Tags: android, listview, youtube-data-api

I want to create a custom listview which will look like the facebook timeline. For that I have created a custom listview. The custom listview will be inflated in the Home fragment which will be the part of MainActivity.

I have created a layout which contains text and images and it is working fine. Now I want to add a youtube player to my feeds too.

Whenever I try to add YouTubePlayerView or YouTubeFragment to the layout of the custom listview the crashes with the error, "Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView"

My question is can it be done?

This is my CustomFeedsList.java class:

```
public class FeedsCustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] UN;
private final Integer[] imageId;
private String[] VideoID;

public FeedsCustomList(Activity context,
                       String[] UN, Integer[] imageId, String[] VideoID) {
    super(context, R.layout.video_list_items, UN);
    this.context = context;
    this.UN = UN;
    this.imageId = imageId;
    this.VideoID = VideoID;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feeds_layout, null, true);

    LoaderMethod(rowView, position);

    return rowView;
}

public void LoaderMethod(final View rowView, final int position){

    ImageView PROFILE = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.feeds_profile_picture_IV);
    TextView USERNAME = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.feeds_username_TV);
    TextView TIMEV = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.feeds_postTime_TV);
    TextView STATUS = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.status_TV);
    ImageView IMAGE = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.feeds_image_IV);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_YT);
   // YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);

    USERNAME.setText(UN[position]);

    PROFILE.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

    TIMEV.setText(UN[position]);

    STATUS.setText(UN[position]);


    if (imageId[position] != 0) {
        IMAGE.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    } else IMAGE.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if (!VideoID[position].equals("null")) {
    }
    else linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}

}
```

This is my Home.java fragment class:

```
public class Home extends Fragment {

public Home() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

final String[] names ={"mic","moneyd","nav_head","thumbnail","status","image"};

Integer[] images = {R.drawable.mic,
        R.drawable.moneyd,
        R.drawable.nav_head,
        R.drawable.thumbnail,
        0,
        R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp};

String[] VideoID = {"null","null","null","null","P3mAtvs5Elc","null"};

ImageView PROFILE;
TextView USERNAME;
TextView TIME;
TextView STATUS;
ImageView IMAGE;
VideoView VIDEO;

ListView feedsList;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    feedsList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.feedList);

    FeedsCustomList adapter = new
            FeedsCustomList(getActivity(), names, images,VideoID);
    feedsList.setAdapter(adapter);

   // VIDEO = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.feeds_video_VV);

   // VIDEO.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    return view;
}

}
```

EDIT: This is the logcat:

```
10-16 17:38:05.621 13311-13322/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
10-16 17:38:07.061 13311-13311/svtinida.shreyans.com.smartschoolindia E/Process: android_os_Process_getProcessNameByPid pid is 13311
10-16 17:38:07.061 13311-13311/svtinida.shreyans.com.smartschoolindia E/Process: android_os_Process_getProcessNameByPid value is martschoolindia
10-16 17:38:08.371 13311-13311/svtinida.shreyans.com.smartschoolindia E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: svtinida.shreyans.com.smartschoolindia, PID: 13311
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #68: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at svtinida.shreyans.com.smartschoolindia.FeedsCustomList.getView(FeedsCustomList.java:54)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2391)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1893)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:708)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:769)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1687)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2195)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15697)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5064)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1692)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1468)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15697)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5064)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15697)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5064)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15697)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5064)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1167)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:852)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:871)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15697)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5064)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1193)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15697)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5064)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15697)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5064)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15697)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5064)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15697)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5064)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15697)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5064)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15697)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5064)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2260)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.perform
```

Comment: What's the full error logcat? Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29911162/how-to-display-youtubeplayerview-in-a-listview-in-android

Comment: @cricket_007 I have added added logcat to the question and thanks for the reference. I'll check if it works.